# Securing S3 Static site hosting redirect to lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am currently running a static website within an S3 Bucket that re-directs to Lambda when a `404` occurs. The problem with this solution is that the Lambda function must be open it to be invoked as I cannot supply an `x-api-key` header as from what I can gather the Re-routing ruleset on S3 Static Hosting do not enable headers to be attached to the request.

Essentially I am just trying to lockdown the Lambda function to only be invoked via our requests whilst sticking with the current static site-hosting routing we are using. These are the two methods I foresee to resolve this issue.

1. Figure out a way to add a header to the redirect.
2. Determine where the request came from and verify it *prior* to the lambda function running.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can add a path like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16877231/2190251

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom static `404.html` page on S3 and have a Javascript in this page to call the Lambda function using Ajax. Then you can use any method, headers and data in the Ajax request to Lambda. You could even use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to use data about your users in order to customize Lambda request/response and even decide whether you should redirect the user or do something else.

If you're not using CloudFront, you can set the error page [like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FLmD.jpg) ([Credits to @Geander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43101013/custom-404-page-for-static-website-using-aws-s3-buckets-not-working#answer-43101444)). In case you are using CloudFront, follow this [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/custom-error-pages.html).

Comment: Thanks for replying - but doesn't adding javascript to a 404.html still leave the same issue of the header containing the api key being exposed to the user?